# Insert/post the contents of a table data into a database

Tags: php, mysql

please i need to insert the value of a table data into the database using a post submit but i dont seem to get it right... The code isn't complete, all i just need is for anyone to put me through the post submit data.

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title        = $_POST[$product['title']];
        $slug         = $_POST[$product['slug']];
        $slug         = $_POST[$product['description']];
        $quantity     = $_POST[$product['quantity']];
        $subTotal     = $_POST[number_format($total, 2) ];
      }
    ?> 
   // i guess my post submit is wrong...

     <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="7"><h3 class="text-center">Order details</h3></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr  class="btn bg-success">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Slug</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    <form method="post" action="cart.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-info" name="title"><?php echo $product['title']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-info"><?php echo $product['slug']; ?> </td>
                        <td class="text-info"><?php echo $product['description']; ?> </td>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success text-right" value="Checkout" onClick="return confirm('you will be redirected .....');" /> <!-- submit button -->

                </table>
All i need is to post to the database after clicking the submit button. Thank You.
```

Comment: any errors being displayed? can you print out the values or are they empty?

Comment: Where are your input tags?

Comment: A `<form>` being submitted would post the contents of form elements, such as `<input>` or `<select>`, etc.  You don't seem to have any of those.  Nor do you even have a complete form (you never close the `</form>` element).  And the table looks malformed to begin with.

Comment: @David i had to remove some code for clarity... My major issue is posting the value of the <td><?php echo $product['slug']; ?></td> and posting into a database.

Comment: @sanmexm: If you removed your form elements then that would indeed be the problem.  Your form has no inputs, selects, textareas, etc. to hold any form values.  It looks like you're successfully posting an empty form.

Comment: does this mean my input tags needs to be inbetween the table data tag.. like this "<td><input type="text" value="<?php code ?>" /></td>

Comment: @david does this mean my input tags needs to be inbetween the table data tag.. like this "<td><input type="text" value="<?php code ?>" /></td>

Comment: @sanmexm: Well, it means you need form elements need to be in the form.  And they need to have `name` attributes.  There's in-depth information and examples of how to build and use HTML forms here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form

Answer (score 0):

To post data into database, you need to submit the form and convert the form variables into PHP variables.

In the form use a name for each field like

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
```

then, after form submission, collect the form data into php variables

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Use this data in a mysql query to post into database.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`slno`,`name`) VALUES ('1','".$name."'");
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score -3):

You cannot post with out input tags. Make sure you have are submitting form from input elements. To get the posted values use the name for the input provided. Ex: $slug = $_POST['slug'];
After getting the post values  into variables insert them into database using mysql queries. I suggest you start from basics of insert query

Comment: does this mean my input tags needs to be inbetween the table data tag.. like this "<td><input type="text" value="<?php code ?>" /></td>

Comment: does this mean my input tags needs to be inbetween the table data tag.. like this "<td><input type="text" value="<?php code ?>" /></td>

Comment: Yes. And also the name you give to the input tag is used in php code to fetch the its value as i have mentioned in my answer